How did Anton become a Higher Other (bypassing First rank)?
Warning: the question itself spoils a very important plot point in Book #3 ("Twilight Watch") of Night Watch cycle. Read at your own risk.
At the start of Book #3 ("Twilight Watch") of Night Watch cycle, protagonist Anton is a Light Other of Second rank. It's mentioned several times in the book:

Женщина, которую я люблю, Иная. И еще — она добровольно отказалась от службы в Дозоре, от блестящей карьеры Великой Волшебницы. Все ради меня, идиота. Чтобы я, упертый навсегда в свой второй уровень силы, не комплексовал (История 1, Глава 4)


The woman I love is the Other. And also, she voluntarily gave up her service in the Watch, her brilliant career as a Great Sorceress. All for me, an idiot. So that I, forever stuck in my second level of power, wouldn't have complexes. (Story 1, Chapter 4)

and

У меня второй уровень — это немало (История 2, Глава 6)


I am second level {{of power}} - that's not a small thing (Story 2, Chapter 6)

Them (SPOILER ALERT)

 Anton is present when Kostya uses the Fuaran book, changing Las from normal human to the Other. As a result, Anton's rank is raised by the same spell since Fuaran's spell has area effect.

And yet, by the end of the book #3, Anton is "Higher Other", outside categories, NOT first rank as I would expect:

«Антон, опомнись. Ты стоял перед Саушкиным, когда он произнес заклинание. У тебя уже не второй уровень».
«А… какой?»
«Выше первого — только одна категория. Высшая...» (История 3, Глава 6)


"Anton, come to your senses. You were standing in front of Saushkin when he cast the spell. You're no longer level two."
"Umm... which one?"
"There's only one category higher than first. The Higher ..."  (Story 3, Chapter 6)

The latter is also confirmed in the very start of Book #4 (story 1, chapter 1):

Ты – Высший маг. Так получилось случайно, но ты – Высший. Почему Высших магов также называют магами вне категорий?


You are a Highest Mage. It happened by chance, but you are a Highest. Why are Highest Mages also called mages beyond categories?

So, why did the spell propel Anton from second rank to Highest rank, instead of to First rank?

What's your basis for believing that use of the Fuaran can only advance by one rank?

Because narratively 1st wouldn't change a thing?

@Kyralessa - I think elsewhere in the book they mentioned that advancing higher and higher needs repeated use of the spell

I think Saushkin got to be absolute with single casting. Either way it's unclear how much this spell was 'upgrading" them and what it depended on.

@Mithoron - He was already a Higher Vampire (IIRC 1st rank equivalent??? not sure) at the start of book #3

I think he was also second, but even then, it would be more than one level.
